# How to spot multiple occurances of an element in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, internet-explorer, render

I'm working on detecting a case in Internet Explorer where the header frame is repeated multiple times in a webpage.

Normally it won't render the header frame multiple times. But sometimes it will. I'm not sure when it does.

How do I detect when such case occurs in python.

I'm new to it. I can get the source code of the page and check if the header's code is repeated multiple times. But that may not be the case here.

I can use selenium to check if the element is present multiple times or not. But that may not be the case if it is problem with rendering in IE.

The only solution I can think of is checking if a particular image exists multiple times in another image.

I can take the screenshot of image at the time of testing and I can have the screenshot of only header.

But how do I check if the header exists multiple times?

Any solution to tackle such problem?